# When can a variable be both null and a function?

Tags: javascript

While tracking down a bug I came across some strange behavior, **why does this happen?**

Note: For reference this code is a result of my JavaScript code behing compressed with the closure compiler.

In chrome the debugger is paused on the thrown error. And I've fired some lines into the console (see below).

```
a
> null
B.Ta.Cd[a]
> "Override this" error is thrown
B.Ta.Cd[null]
> undefined
```

I don't understand that if `a` is supposed to be `null` then why the second two lines do not produce the same thing.

Interestingly I wanted to see how `a` and `null` differ.

```
typeof(a)
> "function"
typeof(null)
> "object"
```

Now I'm wondering how can `a` be both a function and `null`?

[This video shows the tests in the console](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID-bxYX07AI&feature=youtu.be)

My fix was to check for `typeof(a) == "function"` then return. But I don't like adding in fixes for issues I don't understand.

Comment: Can you try `B.Ta.Cd[0]`?  I'd imagine null gets coerced to 0.

Comment: what does your function do? Are you using `==` somewhere? Try changing to `===` and see if you still get the same behaviour..

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: No; it does not.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I've already noticed.  That's what I get for asking first and experimenting later.  Would you recommend I delete the comment to avoid clutter, or leave it for others who would ask the same question?

Comment: No. a function can't be null, null is a primitive value type and functions are objects.

Comment: Having trouble reproducing this now, had to wait 2 hours for that video to upload to youtube, and since then I've made significant progress with my code. Will endeavor to revert and try your suggestion Ed but hoping there's a logical explanation. Your answer you provided @ScottMermelstein made a lot of sense and I thought that could be the reason? But you've removed it.

Comment: @Ally I tested it further, and never got matching results.  Any object that I look at in Chrome debugger doesn't just show the results of `toString`, it shows the whole object.  To others - I thought maybe `a` was a valid function with toString overridden to return null.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I think I figured it out along the lines of what you tried, instead of overriding `toString`, override `valueOf`. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. That's `valueOf` on the a function object, not the prototype.

Comment: @Ally Thanks, but that doesn't seem much different: http://jsfiddle.net/FJm57/ If you type `foo` in the debugger, you get `Foo {valueOf: function}`

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Try http://jsfiddle.net/FJm57/3/

Comment: @Ally you got it.  Feel free to write it up.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based along the lines of ScottMermelstein's thinking (thanks for the help) it turns out the `valueOf` function on the `a` function had been overridden to return null. Therefore trying to see what `a` is in the console turns out to be quite misleading.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJm57/3/) for an example.